# Run jaxws2.2 webservice in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services, jax-ws

I can call webservice which is created on java using jaxws2.2 and it is running well. But when I call that webservice in an android applicatin then one error is that: `E/AndroidRuntime(706): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.xml.ws.Service`

My jdk is 1.7 version, My sdk is r20.0.1 And eclipse is indigo3.6

Comment: present some code or the complete log error

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to keep your jdk to 1.6 check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8578463/582571.

and for that javax.xml.ws.service , i did not found that in developer.android site.

Your question is similar to this question [Having Android Problems with Sun javax jars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3135468/582571).